# Design django Relation to save data easily later

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I have 2 csv's according to which I have to design database.

**first one is**

[image: first table]

And my **2nd csv** is

[image: 2nd csv]

**And My django model code till now is**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='Restaurant')
    RestaurantName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    Location = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=False)
    Logo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='Logo')
    NumberOfTables=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=100 , choices=Availability_CHOICES )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.RestaurantName)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Categories(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class ArticlesOptionsChoices(models.Model):
    articleoption = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    optionname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return str('optionname={0}, choice={1}'.format(self.optionname, self.choice))
        except:
              return str(self.optionname)

class ArticlesOptions(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ManyToManyField(ArticlesOptionsChoices,max_length=255)
    min = models.IntegerField()
    max = models.IntegerField()
    choice=models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptionsChoices, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='user_choice_option')
    choice_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)




class Articles(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    articlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pickuptax = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    dineintax=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)     #done
    articleoption = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptions , on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.articlename)
```

I am assuming a restaurant as a User. So Real issue is now how I will manage `Article Options` into first csv from 2nd csv . I have made **Articles Options** table which will have all data of 2nd csv and futher it have a refrence table **ArticlesOptionsChoices** to keep record of  **Name** and **choice** from 2nd csv .

Its overall hierarchy is like     **1 restaurant - > Many articles**   2nd case   **Every Article - >  Article Options**   3rd   **Article Options -> Many options**  (like topping have 4 options and every restaurant can have multiple options.

Is it okay design overall or I need to make changes ? Suggestions are welcomed.

**Update**  **First Csv text**

```
Article name,Price,Category,Taxrate if pickup,Taxrate if dine in,More information,Ingredient (ability to unselect),Article options
Article1,1.90,Pizza,6%,21%,This is a tekst field with more information about the product,Olives@muchrooms@peperoni,Topping
Article2,2.45,Drinks,6%,21%,This is a tekst field with more information about the product,,Free sauce
Article3,3.00,Pasta,21%,21%,This is a tekst field with more information about the product,,Paid sauce
```

**2nd csv text**

```
Min/max,Name,Choice ,price
0/4,Topping,Cheese,1.0
0/4,Topping,Milk,2.0
0/4,Topping,Olives,0.50
0/4,Topping,Double cheese,2.0
1/1,Free sauce,Ketchup,0.00
1/1,Free sauce,Mayonaise,0.00
1/1,Free sauce,Bicky,0.00
1/1,Free sauce,Curry,0.00
1/1,Free sauce,andalouse,0.00
0/1,Paid sauce,Ketchup,0.80
0/1,Paid sauce,Mayonaise,0.80
0/1,Paid sauce,Bicky,0.80
0/1,Paid sauce,Curry,0.80
0/1,Paid sauce,andalouse,0.80
```

Comment: Please post your CSVs (well, sample of them) as __text__ - images of code are useless.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  Sir how I can upload ? there is only image upload option ?

Comment: Upload ? Why upload ? CSV is a text format, just open your CSVs as text and copy-paste them in your question.

Comment: wrt/ your question, you don't design your relational model based on some random CSVs, you design it based on business rules specified from the problem domain analysis and functional requirements. You can of course use those CSVs as a basis for analysis in a discussion with the customer, and you may even in  some cases ending up with a one-to-one mapping between the CSVs and (part of) the relational model, but that's most often not the case.

Comment: Also there's surely a couple typos in your snippet - ie things like `restaurant = models.ForeignKey(User)`...

Comment: Got it sir @brunodesthuilliers . I just have confusion what will be best practice to manage field 'Article Options' from csv one  according to csv 2nd

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers csv text updated. kindly have a look

Comment: As I already stated, you don't design a relational model based on CSVs, but on proper analysis of the problem domain. If we don't know the business rules, we can't tell whether your relational model is right or wrong (except for all those foreign keys on `User` but I assume those are typos in your snippet, else they wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  sir this was best advice I must say . saved from a big mess

Comment: you're welcome - and glad I could help :-)